# Angular ngrx and Resolver. Find Observable object from observable array by property value

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

I have a resolver that needs to return Organization details from the api service. At the same time we are using ngrx to store the details of all organizations.

I want my resolver to look into the ngrx store:
- populate it with list of Organizations if it is empty
- find Organization with specific id from the ngrx store and return it.

The way i am trying to do it now:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Organization> {

const organizationId = route.paramMap.get(RouterHelperService.urlParam.organizationId);
this.initOrganizationsData();

const company = this.store.select(store => store.companies)
  .filter(state => state && state.length > 0 && state.filter(c => c.id === organizationId).length > 0)
  .take(1)[0];

return company;
}
```

and here is the method initOrganizationsData():

```
private initOrganizationsData(): void {
this.store.take(1).subscribe(store => {
  if (store.companies.length === 0) {
    this.organizationService.getOrganizations().subscribe(data => {
      this.store.dispatch(new companyActions.LoadCompaniesSuccessAction(data));
    });
  }
});
```

}

At the moment I always get the the result Company **is undefined**.

Can anyone point me into the right direction. What is wrong? How to get `Observable<Organization>` from `Observable<Organization[]>` with specific value?

Comment: The solution to the answer lives here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945894/filter-array-for-angular2-ngrx

Comment: `flatten` should work